# Android MediaPlayer.create() returns null when uri has spaces

Tags: android, null, uri, android-mediaplayer

I noticed on my app that Android MediaPlayer.create() returns null for uri's with a space,
for examplehttps://zzzzzzzzzz.amazonaws.com/my songs/song18.mp3"

whereas uri's without spaces work just fine.

This worked perfectly in previous versions of the app and only happens now on the new version.

In updating to current version I did not change any code relating to the MediaPlayer.
What could be causing this issue?

Any way I can prevent this?

Comment: I was able to avoid crashing by replacing any spaces using `replaceAll("\\s","%20")`.     So now I create the uri like this:  
`uri = Uri.parse(dbPageItem.getAudio().replaceAll("\\s","%20"));`   
But my Question still stands, why did this suddenly not parse the spaces?

Comment: in url space is not allowed. you can try with different url and check if it is working or not

Comment: But there always were spaces in this url and it had always worked, it must have changed along the way somewhere, anyways i used `replaceAll()` just to be safe since i don't control creating the url's.